# WP Query filters active on wrong query

Tags: wp-query, filters

I'm running several filters on WP_Query on a specific query, simply because I had to. I add these filters right before I run the query and remove them inside the callback functions. The Query Monitor plugins shows that the filters aren't active but as soon as I run a regular WP_Query elsewhere in my code the generated SQL query shows me that the filters are actually still added, breaking basic WP_Queries.

An example of one of the filters is

```
public function add_select_views($select) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 20);
    $select .= ", SUM(views.count) as totalviews";
    return $select;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the filters are still added to my 'regular' WP_Query?

Addition: These filters are added in REST endpoints, if that matters at all.

Comment: once filters are added to a query, they must be remove right after the query, otherwise they affect any query.

Comment: That's why I remove them within the filter themselves. I see loads of plugins that do it this way and none of those filters are active except my own.

Comment: Can you post your code that also has the add_filter please? The remove filter should have the name of the filter as first param, if I'm not mistaken. Are you sure current_filter() echoes the name of your filter?

Comment: It's declared in a class, it's simple add_filter( 'posts_fields', [ $this, 'posts_fields_filter'], 20, 1);
That's why the remove_filter uses current_filter() and __FUNCTION__ which should work just fine.

Comment: Understood. But if you var_dump the current_filter() just before you call it, is it 'post_fields'? Just to be absolutely sure you are removing the filter you want and not some other one, added by some other plugin.

Comment: Yes, but removing it as remove_filter('posts_fields', [$classVar, 'posts_fields_filter], 20]); also doesn't work.

My problem itself is solved by simply rewriting entire custom queries for these REST endpoints, but I still don't understand why the filters aren't removed. Also interestingly enough if on other places I would dump the WP_Query request it would show the query with all my filters, but the returned posts would not be from that query as directly inserting it in my databasewould return 0 rows.